Change the min-width in Listitem and ListItemIcon on React MaterialUI
I want to change the minWidth of the ListItemIcon:
space between the ListItemIcon and ListItemText
This is I want to achieve:
What I want
But this is what I achieve:
the ListItemIcon is in the center
This is what I tried to do:
return (
<ListItem
  component="li"
  sx={{
    padding: 0,
  }}
>
  <Link
    to={linkTo}
    style={{
      textDecoration: "none",
      color: "inherit",
      width: "100%",
      padding: "16px",
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
    }}
  >
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Icon
        sx={{
          color: isActive ? "black" : `${color}`, // Cambia il colore se attivo
          stroke: isActive ? "black" : `${color}`,
          strokeWidth: `${strokeWidth}`,
          // minWidth: "1", // <-- UNCOMMENT THIS
        }}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      disableTypography
      primary={
        <Typography
          variant="body2"
          style={{
            color: isActive ? "black" : `${color}`, // Cambia il colore se attivo
            fontWeight: isActive ? "700" : fontWeight, // Aggiungi il grassetto se attivo
            fontSize: "1.3em",
          }}
        >
          {text}
        </Typography>
      }
    />
  </Link>
</ListItem>);

EDIT: The "Icon" type is
React.ElementType<SvgIconProps>

